# React Native - NativeBase extendTheme Custom Components not Loading Initially

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components, native-base

I have a custom component for Buttons using NativeBase, and it seems work great initially; once I restart the project, the default style for the button I have set no longer works. To fix this, I have to manually set a variation, and then remove it, like so :

```
<Button variation="random" /> // Sets the variation to something random

<Button /> // delete the variation section of button, and now the default loads
```

I have it set up like so:

```
export const style = extendTheme({
    components:{
      Button: {
        baseStyle: {
          rounded: 'lg',
        },
        defaultProps: {
          size: 'sm',
          colorScheme: 'green',
          _text: {
            color: 'white',
            fontSize: '30px',
            ...fonts.h1, //custom font
            margin: -2,
          }
        },
      }
    }
```

Then, within App.js:

```
const style = style // from import

return (
 <NativeBaseProvider theme={style}>
  <NavigationContainer>
   <StackNavigator>
    ...etc.
)
```

And finally, in another file:

```
<Button />
```

Why is this occurring? I assume it has something to do with NativeBaseProvider wrapping everything in App.js, instead of just wrapping each individual file using the custom components with it.

Thanks!